# Post or Put method for insert new data in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.NET and I want to ask which method is more preferred for insert new rows in SQL Server.

The biggest problem I want to avoid is double insert data into SQL Server. Maybe for some network delay I will take server error in my client's application, but server have received my data and insert them into SQL Server. When I will make a retry, it will re-insert them.

Does post or put method can avoid this? Or i need to create my own mechanism?

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}

// PUT api/values/5
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

Also one last question, can I create two post methods inside same controller or I have to create a new one?

Sorry, if questions looks easy but as I said I am new in asp.net. Thank you

Comment: No. The Post or Put methods have nothing to do with that. You can use some tools like Polly or hangfire for this purpose.

Comment: Whatever problem you're trying to describe doesn't seem like it would have anything to do with the HTTP verb(s) used.  From an HTTP purist perspective, in general POST adds a record to the resource and PUT updates (replaces) a record on the resource.  In general practice PUT is rarely used and nearly everything is done with POST (write) or GET (read).  But, again, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with whatever problem you may be trying to track down.

Comment: So in a rest api it doesn't matter what method i use. Right?

Comment: @Dim It does matter. Even if you can insert on a PUT. You could even insert a user on a DELETE method. The thing is that REST standards exists for a reason.

Comment: So the all thing thing it's more typical to follow asp net rules for what you want to do. Right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

POST or PUT methods does not solve nothing by itself. If you want to avoid the behaviour you described you should solve that by adding your own logic to that methods. It is your implementation what have to make the control over if the data exists or not.

Ideally on REST API, POST will be for creating a resource and PUT is for updating an existing resource.

Having said that, you can implement your logic depending on who is calling that endpoint and in what instance of the application. For example, if someone send a POST with the same resource two times, you can check out if the resource exists and send an HTTP status that describe the situation.

EDIT:

I will add some code to show you. How it could work:

Let´s suppose you want to create and update users in your application. The endpoint for that could be something like: http://localhost:8080/api/users/ using POST method and sending the user as JSON on the request body.

You will have a UsersController something like this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]UserModel user)
    {
        SQL.InsertUser(user);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

Then on the data layer you could make something like this:

```
    public static void InsertUser(UserModel user)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                _conn.Execute(@"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID = @ID)
                                BEGIN
                                    /*DO THE UPDATE*/
                                END
                            ELSE
                                BEGIN
                                    /*DO THE INSERT*/
                                END", user);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

This is not the optimal approach but what I´m trying to show here is that you can either insert the resource on POST or on PUT. The thing is that RESTful API´s are meant to be designed following the RESTful standard. If you insert data with a PUT method then you probably have and architecture issue and your API isn´t RESTful at all. Even if it uses the HTTP methods form communication and so.

It is very important on RESTful API´s to follow the standard. For you and the people that make use of the API.

Here you got a RESTful introductory bible. I usually send this to everyone that is looking to undestand RESTful world: https://blog.octo.com/en/design-a-rest-api/

Comment: Thank you Nico nice explanation, I am confused when you said creating a resource, do you mean for insert data in sql server? Does it change anything if i will use post instead? Or it's more performanced?

Comment: Also a though in my problem is to create a list collection with a request ID and a client ID for each request. Then to lock my list each time i write or read something. Correct me if i am wrong, or if other mechanisms are more stable.

Comment: Thank you nico once again. I am looking for learning things correctly. Nice thought to look into sql server if there is this id, also if you can send me a link which is the optimal way for this. Also one last question, can i create two post method in same controller with different routes? Or i need to create new controller?

Comment: You cannot have two POST method on the same controller. Create a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Post() method that we decorated with a [HttpPost] attribute.

Put() is able to update something in a RESTful service